# OnClickListener Issue on Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, onclick, onclicklistener

I have an issue about event OnClickListener on Fragment.

- I am using Android Studio 3.1
- this is capture of my source code :

  ---

  [image]

  focus to yellow highlight, if source code i give comment statement when 
  running it's already OK. But when i uncomment that, it makes my app force 
  close.

  And then i tried change the method by giving event `onClick` on XML, but can't 
  using `method` in class
  [image]

Comment: "this is capture of my source code :" - because a copy paste of the code is much harder?

Comment: You have implemented View.OnClickListener.So you must implement OnClick(View v) method.Write your code in that OnClick().

Comment: OnClick(View v) already exist, because when i implemented View.OnClickListener must be exist. But the method still empty

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `View` parameter if you declare `android:onclick="method"` in your XML.

Also you need to declare this method in your *activity* (not in the fragment).

```
public void method(View view)
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Button is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

in Java code,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Button is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }     
});
```

Comment: if run on debugging mod, the result debug :

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: it clearly says, Your button is null. Can you please add the changed code in your question

Comment: You can set onclicklistener in java code like my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class UncompleteFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
    private SimpleAdapter sa;
    private HashMap<String,String> item;
    private ListView listView;
    private Button btnEdit;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.uncomplete, container, false);
        listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        btnEdit = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit_uncomplete);
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button Edit Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for(int i=0;i<uncomplete.length;i++){
            item = new HashMap<String,String>();
            item.put( "line1", uncomplete[i][0]);
            item.put( "line2", uncomplete[i][1]);
            item.put( "line3", uncomplete[i][2]);
            item.put( "line4", uncomplete[i][3]);
            list.add( item );
        }

        sa = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list,
                R.layout.uncomplete_list,
                new String[] { "line1","line2","line3","line4"},
                new int[] {R.id.date,R.id.check_in,R.id.check_out,R.id.work_hour});

        listView.setAdapter(sa);
    }

    private String[][] uncomplete =
            {{"12 Apr 2018","08:00","14:00","05:00"},
             {"27 Mar 2018","00:00","00:00","00:00"},
             {"06 Feb 2018","08:00","00:00","00:00"}};

    public void doEdit() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button Edit Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Comment: @Jyoti JK, i use your recommendation source code, but the result the button still null